# KeyError: ('url', ' text')

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i'm making a discord bot and when I try to run the command I get KeyError: ('url', 'text')

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def test(ctx):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://api-to.get-a.life/meme') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            await bot.say(res["url", "text"])
```

Comment: Should there be a `.` or parentheses instead of a space here: `res = await r.json()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using two keys to get value out of dictionary it is wrong syntax either use

`res["url"]` or `res["text"]`

like

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def test(ctx):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://api-to.get-a.life/meme') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            url = res["url"]
            text = res["text"]
            await bot.say(url, text) # or whatever parameter your bot accepts
```

Comment: how is `def say(...):` defined ?

Comment: @Patrick:  f*** , thats too much room for couple of params. Now only OP knows how to send them....